# Desugaring 'do' blocks

Tags: haskell, syntax, monads

I'm having little trouble translating this `do` statement :

```
ex10 :: [Int]
ex10 = do
    num <- [1..20]
    guard (even num)
    guard (num `mod` 3 == 0)
    return num
```

into some kind of `monad` syntax like this :

```
ex10' :: [Int]
ex10' = [1..20] >>= (guard . even) >>= (guard . (==0) . (mod 3)) >>= \r -> return r
```

This doesn't work, and I'm not quite sure why. I think I might have misunderstood `guard` but am not sure in what way.

Comment: You're missing the `num` binding. You need to name it at the first `>>=` so that you can reuse it in subsequent terms.

Comment: Also note that `>>` is used instead of `>>=` for lines which don't have `<-`.

Comment: The code you wrote is the translation for `do { num <- [1..20]; x <- guard (even num); r <- guard (x \`mod\` 3 == 0); return r }`.

Comment: Any time you have two guards in a row, you can collapse them into one. Can you see how? Can you see a way to combine the underlying mathematical questions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`guard` has type `MonadPlus m => Bool -> m ()` so your third segment

```
(guard . (==0) . (mod 3))
```

receives a value of type `()` which is not what you want. In `do` notation

```
do
  guard (even num)
  guard (num `mod` 3 == 0)
```

is desugarded into something like

```
guard (even num) >> guard (num `mod` 3 == 0)
```

so you can implement `ex10'` as

```
 ex10' = [1..20] >>= (\num -> (guard $ even num) >> (guard $ num `mod` 3 == 0) >> return num)
```